# Get Request Submitting as a Post Request

Tags: callout

i am sending a GET request to a spring boot backend api, but i keep getting a 405 error, POST method not allowed

my code is

```
public class TextingSolution {


private final Contact xReceiver {get;set;}
public String MessageContent{get;set;}
public Boolean Success {get;set;}
// public integer reloadTime ;


public TextingSolution(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    Id xId= System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Id');
    this.xReceiver = [Select Name, Phone From Contact Where Id=:xId];

}
public void ClosePopUp(){
    this.Success = false;

}
public void showPopUp(){
    this.Success = true;
}


public  PageReference SendMessage(){
    // perform Apex Callout Here
    String jsonBody = '{"phoneNumber":' +JSON.serialize(this.xReceiver.Phone) +', "text":'+ JSON.serialize(this.MessageContent)+'}';
    System.debug(jsonBody);
    PageReference page = ApexPages.currentPage();

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest Request = new HttpRequest();

   //configure request
    Request.setEndpoint('http://3.19.59.9:8080/api/v1/sendMessage');
    Request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    Request.setBody(jsonBody);
    Request.setMethod('GET');

    system.debug(request);

    // send request, get response!
    HttpResponse Response = http.send(Request);
    System.debug('Response: ' +  Response.getBody());
    //if(Response.getStatusCode()==200){
      //  this.Success= true;
      //System.debug('Successful: '+ this.Success);
        page.setRedirect(true);

    //}else this.Success = false;

return  page;
}
```

}

but i get this response in the Debug

```
10:35:20:105 USER_DEBUG [43]|DEBUG|Response: <html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Mon Nov 18 09:35:20 UTC 2019</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).</div><div>Request method &#39;POST&#39; not supported</div></body></html>
```

somehow, the web api is seeing my request as a POST request. When i tested in PostMan with a get request, it worked, while with post request i got the error 405. 
any fixes ??

Comment: is it working via any rest client like postman?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to set a body on a GET request, which is not normal. There's some discussion on the subject of whether or not a body is allowed in a GET request, but the simple advice is not to do it.

> any HTTP request message is allowed to contain a message body, and
>   thus must parse messages with that in mind. Server semantics for GET,
>   however, are restricted such that a body, if any, has no semantic
>   meaning to the request. The requirements on parsing are separate from
>   the requirements on method semantics.
>
> So, yes, you can send a body with GET, and no, it is never useful to do so.

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

If you remove the body from your code, you'll find SF sends it as a GET. Put it back in, and it gets converted to a POST.

Looking at your code, you're trying to set up an API to send a message. In which case, POST is probably the right HTTP verb anyway. So I'd change the spring end to expect and accept a POST.

If you really can't do that, you'll have to put your body into the URL as a request parameter.

Comment: In practice, I've observed that servers tend to see the body of a GET as a new request, and will end up throwing a 400 Bad Request error on the "second" request.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you were correct